# R Assign to the ith index in a list, the name of which is called variably in a loop?

Tags: r, list, variables, indexing, assign

First, this is a tough one to explain, particularly given that I am new to coding/R and its nomenclature, so I appreciate your patience and time (Destiny reference!).

I have a list of data frame names, in a loop I pull one out, then I enter a second loop, in which I want to assign() a value to the current (inner loop) iteration of that name. In other words, In an inner loop I want to iteratively assign values to a data frame, the name of which changes in the outer loop.

```
names <- c("alex","bec","kate")
states <- c("ACT","NSW","QLD","NT")

for (i in seq_along(names)){
    count <- 1
    curr.name = names[i]  #get current name
    assign(curr.name,list()) #preallocate list

    for (j in seq_along(states)) {
         x = matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1*j), ncol=10) #example data
         assign(curr.name[[count]], colMeans(x)) #here's my problem
        count <- count+1
    }
}
```

Once it gets to count==2, it tells me that subscript is out of bounds, because it is trying to assign the values to curr.name(2), which doesn't exist. I instead want to assign those values to the jth index of the curr.name, i.e. alex[[2]], so that it looks like

```
> alex
[[1]]
 [1] 1.952008 2.387436 1.745254 2.532774 3.174661 2.616323 1.713760 1.417643 3.328726
[10] 2.951489

[[2]]
 [1] 2.007752 2.856600 2.702416 1.370758 2.496893 2.383102 2.987076 2.838724 2.386669
[10] 2.125972

etc. 4 sets of means (one for each state) per name.
```

There are likely better way to organise my data, however I am working on someone else's code and for the meanwhile I'd just like to get things working for them before looking at how we can optimise it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try changing `1:seq_along(states)` to just `seq_along(states)` in the  `j` loop

Comment: @Richard Scriven of course, thanks Richard for spotting that oversight. That does not solve the overall issue though, should it?

Comment: So the result should be a list of three, each one a list of length four?

Comment: It should be 4 sets of means (one for each state), for each name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your problematic line by this code:

```
assign(curr.name,c(get(curr.name),list(colMeans(x))))
```

Of course, it leaves a lot of room for optimization.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I know it probably isn't ideal, but i couldn't get the other suggestion to work with my limited R skills.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way using nested `lapply()` calls

```
## set up a function to do the work on each list element
f <- function(x) colMeans(matrix(rexp(200, rate =.1 * x), ncol = 10))
## run the loops 
out <- lapply(setNames(, names), function(a) lapply(seq_along(states), f))
## view the result
str(out)
# List of 3
# $ alex:List of 4
# ..$ : num [1:10] 14.71 10.83 8.78 9.07 11.75 ...
# ..$ : num [1:10] 4.83 5.62 4.39 6.21 3.64 ...
# ..$ : num [1:10] 3.06 3.75 2.89 3.16 3.13 ...
# ..$ : num [1:10] 1.45 3.01 3.57 2.82 3.52 ...
# $ bec :List of 4
# ..$ : num [1:10] 7.78 10.2 11.63 5.52 16.48 ...
# ..$ : num [1:10] 5.75 4.82 4.14 4.51 3.21 ...
# ..$ : num [1:10] 2.5 4.44 3.26 2.72 4.62 ...
# ..$ : num [1:10] 2.19 2.5 1.9 2.88 2.51 ...
# $ kate:List of 4
# ..$ : num [1:10] 8.24 16.52 9.41 7.71 11.72 ...
# ..$ : num [1:10] 4.78 5.46 3.43 4.64 4.64 ...
# ..$ : num [1:10] 4.18 2.58 3.59 3.96 4.04 ...
# ..$ : num [1:10] 2.38 2.68 2.31 2.01 4.18 ...
```